# Using holder.js in Grails application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, holder.js

I am trying to add a carousel slider.

```
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#6a6a6a/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#5a5a5a/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Now i want to know what the following line is:

```
      <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#5a5a5a/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
```

I am using Grails and i added the following lines of code in the `ApplicationResources.groovy` file

```
holder {
    dependsOn 'bootstrap'

    resource url: [dir: 'js', file: 'holder.js']
}
```

I also manually downloaded and added the `holder.js` file in `web-app/js` folder. But still i don't see the image.

Help ?

Answer (score 0):

DO you have this on top of your page :

```
<r:require modules="holder" />
<r:layoutResources />
```

bootstrap can be jquery , holder ,based on your dependencies  .
And this ?

> ApplicationResource.groovy

```
      modules = {
        bootstrap {
            resource url:'js/bootstrap.js'
        }

 holder {
            dependsOn 'bootstrap' 
            resource url:'js/holder.js'
        }
}
```